# npm conundrum: how to run an app continously, with tests?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, nodemon, superagent

I am developing a MANE (Node + Express + Mongo + Angular) app.
While developing, I currently use a `package.json` file like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha",
}
```

So that, when I start developing. I run `npm start`, and `nodemon` starts watching my sources, restarting express server when anything changes.
If I want to run tests, I run `npm test`, and mocha tests are done.
Since I also need testing routes, I have to run `npm start` (in a terminal window) and then `npm test` (in a second terminal window).
So far so good.
But what if I want to re-run tests on every change?
I did try something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run test && nodemon ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha",
}
```

But this doesn't work, since, when test are done, nodemon is not yet started, so I get this error:

```
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000] to deeply equal null
```

By the other hand, I can't reverse the order of the commands (`nodemon ./bin/www && npm run test`), since nodemod is blocking...

Any clue how to solve this "conundrum"?

Comment: have you tried using `restart` and `start` events? https://github.com/remy/nodemon#triggering-events-when-nodemon-state-changes

Comment: This someway works, but `nodemon` events have to be handled in a file different by `package.json` (`nodemon.json`), which could complicate interaction with other `package.json` script actions... I'd prefer having everything in **one** json file (even eventually giving up with `nodemon`)...

Comment: **and**, with something like `"restart": "echo 'nodemon restarted' && npm run-script test"` in `nodemon.json`, every test is run twice, for some concurrency problem... :-(